# LINQ query not returning results that I expect

Tags: c#, linq

Hopefully this is just a simple case of me not seeing some minor detail...

I'm playing with LINQ examples.  Here's a simple class that I created:

```
    public class Art
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
    }
```

And here's the sample coding that I was creating:

```
    public static void Example0000()
    {
        List<Art> art = new List<Art>();
        art.Add(new Art() { Price = 45, Type = "painting" });
        art.Add(new Art() { Price = 123, Type = "sculpture" });
        art.Add(new Art() { Price = 2, Type = "icon" });
        art.Add(new Art() { Price = 460, Type = "sculpture" });
        art.Add(new Art() { Price = 2030, Type = "painting" });
        art.Add(new Art() { Price = 10, Type = "icon" });
        art.Add(new Art() { Price = 700, Type = "painting" });
        art.Add(new Art() { Price = 1400, Type = "sculpture" });
        art.Add(new Art() { Price = 46, Type = "painting" });
        art.Add(new Art() { Price = 12000, Type = "sculpture" });
        art.Add(new Art() { Price = 6, Type = "icon" });
        art.Add(new Art() { Price = 810, Type = "sculpture" });
        art.Add(new Art() { Price = 250, Type = "painting" });
        art.Add(new Art() { Price = 3, Type = "icon" });
        art.Add(new Art() { Price = 1000, Type = "painting" });
        art.Add(new Art() { Price = 260, Type = "sculpture" });

        var artprices =
            from a in art
            group a by a.Type into g
            let maxPrice = g.Max(a => a.Price)
            select new { ArtType = g.Key, MostExpensive = g.Where(a => a.Price == maxPrice) };

        dataGridView1.DataSource = artprices.ToArray();
    }
```

What I am looking for is a two column table, with the highest price "paid" for each type of artwork.  So the table should have:

"painting "      2030

"sculpture"    12000

"icon"            10

Instead, I am not seeing any numbers in the second column.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than finding the max and checking for artwork of that price, I would just order it. I'm not great with query syntax, but this is what I would do.

```
var artprices = art.GroupBy(c => c.Type)
                   .Select(c => new
                                {
                                    ArtType = c.Key,
                                    MostExpensive = c.OrderByDescending(x => x.Price).First()
                                });
```

Having sorts is always unfortunate, but it's probably the best for your case here.

That all said, I'm also not sure why you'd be expecting *numbers* in your second column. If you just want the maximum price for that art type, and not the art itself, that's different from what you have.

```
var artprices = art.GroupBy(c => c.Type)
                   .Select(c => new
                                {
                                    ArtType = c.Key,
                                    MostExpensive = c.Max(x => x.Price)
                                });
```

My suspicion, if I am understanding you correctly, is that your column is looking for a number type, and you're feeding it an `Art`, so it's printing out no contents. I could be wrong, it's hard without knowing a bit more about your setup. But that's my guess. If that's the case, my latter query here should help you.

Answer (score 0):

The anonymous type of the enumeration result of your expression has members ArtType, having type string, and (most important) MostExpensive, having type IEnumerable<Art>. In other words, there are potentially two different problems: first, if you want the second column to be a single value, you need to return a single value, not an enumeration of values. Second, the type of the value you want is int, not Art.

I think what you want is this expression instead:

```
var artprices =
    from a in art
    group a by a.Type into g
    select new { ArtType = g.Key, MostExpensive = g.Max(a => a.Price) };
```